# How to perform XSL Transformation using XMLTABLE in pl sql?

Tags: xslt, plsql

1.For the following code I am not getting any output. DBMS output window showing nothing after executing this code. What could be the problem?
2.Here I have tried to get only one name by referring an attribute [@id="1"] , is it possible to get all the names?

```
    declare
    x varchar(100);
    c1 sys_refcursor;
    xml clob:=
   '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Com>
      <Employee id="1">
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Age>21</Age>
        <Phone>111111111</Phone>
      </Employee>
      <Employee id="2">
        <Name>Adam</Name>
        <Age>22</Age>
        <Phone>22222222</Phone>
      </Employee>
      <Employee id="3">
        <Name>David</Name>
        <Age>22</Age>
        <Phone>333333333</Phone>
      </Employee>
      <Employee id="4">
        <Name>Roy</Name>
        <Age>22</Age>
        <Phone>44444444</Phone>
      </Employee>
    </Com>';

    xsl clob:=
    '<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <xsl:transform version="1.0"                                                              xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
     <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="Com/Employee[@id=''1'']">
     <![CDATA[<Com>]]>
     <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
     <![CDATA[</Com>]]>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
     </xsl:transform>';



    function fun1 return sys_refcursor
    as
    c2 sys_refcursor;
    begin
    open c2 for select Names_List from XMLTABLE('/Com/Employee' 
    PASSING XMLTYPE(XMLTRANSFORM(xmltype(xml),xmltype(xsl)).GetClobVal())
    columns Names_List varchar(100) path 'Name');
    return c2;
    end;
    begin
    c1:=fun1;
    loop
    fetch c1 into x;
    exit when c1%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('Names : '|| x);
    end loop;
    end;
```

Comment: just remove `[@id=''1'']` and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the OPEN C2 ... with this:

```
  OPEN c2 FOR SELECT Names_List FROM XMLTABLE('/Com'  PASSING XMLTRANSFORM(xmltype(xml),xmltype(xsl)) columns Names_List varchar(100) path '/Com');
```

When you get errors, make it step by step. After XMLTRANSFORM you have:

```
<Com>John</Com>
```

There is no Employee tag. Than XMLTRANSFORM returns XMLType. You are getting from XMLType a CLOB and convert it in XMLType. Why?